# Improper convergent integral with interior singularity

Tags: real-analysis

For $a$ and $b$ real numbers, $a<b$, I'm looking for an example of a function $f(x)$ that has an infinite discontinuity at some $c$ satisfying $a<c<b$ (i.e. $c$ is in the interior of the domain of integration) and such that

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

is finite. I tried $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}$ but did not work (integral diverges). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more examples:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x^2}}\,\text{d}x = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\,\text{d}x = 4$$ is finite, but has an infinite discontinuity at $x=0$.

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}\,\text{d}x = 6$$
again has an infinite discontinuity at $x=0$.

---

More generally, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n$ odd, and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m<n$, then any integral of the form
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x^m}}\,\text{d}x$$
will converge, and in fact, 
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{x^m}}\,\text{d}x = \begin{cases}0 & m \text{ odd}\\
\frac{2n}{n-m} & m\text{ even}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you want the absolute value inside the square root.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt{(\sqrt{x})^2}=|\sqrt{x}|$, which is not what's in the integrand.

Comment: Quite right...corrected. Thanks. I think I was originally planning to type what @user210190 wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Both limits, right and left, at $0$ going to $-\infty$:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \ln (|x|) dx=2$$

One going to $\infty$ and another to $-\infty$:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \ln (|x|) \text{sgn} (x)dx=0$$